# How to get name of called hook on Whmcs?

Tags: hook, invoke, whmcs

I am new in Whmcs.
As I know when one Hook called ,whmcs will seek for any add_call in the modules for this hook.
I want to find out which hook at the time is called.
I want to know which hook is called in the process, without edit any files of hooks.
example : when customer adds fund hook x will called and system look for any add_call for it.but i want the module to get any hook that occurs.(like event listener)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show us some effort and specific question - do not expect the community to give you a complete solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you need a global hook, which according to my knowledge is not available.

If you're debugging, there is a setting in the General Settings: Hooks Debug Mode, it will list all executed hooks in the Activity Log.

Other option would be adding a function, and redirect all hooks to it, e.g.:

```
function customCatchAllHooks($vars) {
    $trace = debug_backtrace();
    //Get calling function
    if (isset($trace[1])) {
        $info = $trace[1]['args'];
        $hook = $info[0];
        $params = $info[1];

        error_log(print_r([$hook, $params], true), 3, __DIR__.'/hooks.log');

    }

}

//List of hooks, added just two as an example:
add_hook('ClientAreaPageProfile', 1, 'customCatchAllHooks');
add_hook('ClientEdit', 1, 'customCatchAllHooks');
//and so on...
```

Comment: thank you for your attention.I need the function way.but $trace doesn't return any information about hooks.any idea?

Comment: welcome. I tested this code and it is working. You need to visit a client profile page (Login as client then visit details) or edit client from admin side for this example to give you results.